# django left outer join with condition

Tags: python, django, join, left-join

how to put condition in left outer join query in django.I have given sample query in below.

I need equivalent django query for below sql query.

Table 1

```
class LeadGroups(Audit):

    user            = models.ForeignKey(User)
    group_name      = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Table 2

```
class lead(Audit):

 group        = models.ForeignKey(LeadGroups, null='true', blank='true')
 First_Name      = models.CharField(max_length=255, null='true', blank='true')
 Last_Name       = models.CharField(max_length=255, null='true', blank='true')
```

Required query

```
SELECT "lead_leadgroups"."id", "lead_leadgroups"."created_by_id", "lead_leadgroups"."modified_by_id", "lead_leadgroups"."created_at", "lead_leadgroups"."modified_at", "lead_leadgroups"."customer_id", "lead_leadgroups"."user_id", "lead_leadgroups"."group_name", COUNT("lead_lead"."id") AS "totlacontact" FROM "lead_leadgroups"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "lead_lead" ON ( "lead_leadgroups"."id" = "lead_lead"."group_id" and **"lead_lead"."data_value" = True**) 
WHERE ("lead_leadgroups"."customer_id" = 309 ) GROUP BY "lead_leadgroups"."id", "lead_leadgroups"."created_by_id", "lead_leadgroups"."modified_by_id", "lead_leadgroups"."created_at", "lead_leadgroups"."modified_at", "lead_leadgroups"."customer_id", "lead_leadgroups"."user_id", "lead_leadgroups"."group_name" 
ORDER BY "lead_leadgroups"."id" ASC LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Post your model code - it's not possible to construct a query without that.

Comment: @solarissmoke check now